# Reload list of data inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

In my jsp page, at the time of loading I add model attribute with some data. Then it displays this list in jsp page as follows.

```
<c:forEach var="pattern" items="${patterns}">
               <li class="list-group-item liitem"><strong>${pattern.id}:</strong>
                  <span class="pull-right">${pattern.name}</span>
               </li>
</c:forEach>
```

here is the controller that I'm calling to load the page.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printWelcome(ModelMap model){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("arcane") ;
   List<Pattern> patternList=patternDao.patternList();
    mav.addObject("patterns", patternList);
    return mav;
}
```

Question is when the list get changed, how can I apply those changes without reloading the whole page. Can I call a seperate controller and refresh only a one "div" tag inside jsp.

Comment: have an ajax call to the newly created/updated view and place it where you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. In the end, you have to make an asynchronous ( [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) ) call to the server (=[ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))) either via

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) ( a shorthand for the first one) or [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
The preferred way is to do it with `$.ajax()` / `$.get()` and do the rendering clientside; either using [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) or some kind of templating framework like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [moustache](http://mustache.github.io/) if you like beards. An alternate approach to clientside templating is using something like [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/).

If you want to keep the load on the client as low as possible, you could use `$.load()` to retrieve prerendered results and simply put that in place.